# How do I make my fixed navbar unfixed when it is a smaller screen using bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to make it so when your browser page is smaller, or if you are on a mobile phone you don't see the navbar sticking to the top. I want it to be like the navbar of the bootstrap site: https://getbootstrap.com/

Here is my code:

```
<nav class="navbar fixed-top navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">navbalk</a>
                <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent"
                aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
           </nav>
```

Comment: @chiel Hoogma If you give fixed property to a `.fixed-top` class than in media query remove that class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your style.css

```
.fixed-top{
   position: sticky;
   ...
}
```

With media query you can achieve as

```
@media (max-width: 768px){
  .fixed-top {
    position: static;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
.fixed-top{
   position: fixed;
   top:0;
}
```

Use this might help

Answer (score -2):

> you can use postion sticky and mediaquery to controll the same (Run the snippet in full screen)

```html
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<style>
.bd-navbar {
    position: -webkit-sticky;
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 1;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .bd-navbar {
    position: static;
    top: unset;
}
}

</style>
</head>     

<body>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="bd-navbar d-flex flex-column flex-md-row align-items-center p-3 px-md-4 mb-3 bg-white border-bottom shadow-sm">
  <h5 class="my-0 mr-md-auto font-weight-normal">Company name</h5>
  <nav class="my-2 my-md-0 mr-md-3">
    <a class="p-2 text-dark" href="#">Features</a>
    <a class="p-2 text-dark" href="#">Enterprise</a>
    <a class="p-2 text-dark" href="#">Support</a>
    <a class="p-2 text-dark" href="#">Pricing</a>
  </nav>
  <a class="btn btn-outline-primary" href="#">Sign up</a>
</div>
<div class="pt-md-3 pb-md-4" style="height:100vh;">
</div>
</body>
```